# NVM global module folder

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am using NVM and I am trying to install global NPM modules. That action requires permissions to a folder that I don't have permissions to. With regular node.js/npm that was easy to solve with `prefix` configuration but NVM explicitly forbids it.

What is the right way to change the path to global modules folder in NVM?

Comment: Doesn't nvm install itself inside your home folder by default?

Comment: No, for global modules it tries to access /usr/local/bin/ to create symlinks to executables there.

Comment: install it without `-g` and you have `node_modules/.bin` to use

Comment: Have you tried sudo chown +R $user $directory ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To see the location of the current version of node you are using:

```
nvm which current
```

You are using the system installation if .nvm is not in the path, similar to the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

To switch to a version managed by nvm:

```
nvm use 4
```

To verify you are using a version managed by nvm:

```
nvm which current
```

You should see something similar to the following:

```
/Users/<your-user-name>/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/node
```

You should only experience global install permission issues when you are using the system installation.

Comment: is the above solution still relevant

nvm which current not works on gitbash or cmd prompt.

I have a situation where I installed 8.12.0 using nvm and deleted 8.9.2 which was previously installed without nvm 

if i check global package list it only shows npm and the path is /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm

my previous global packages location /c/Users/Charlie/AppData/Roaming/npm/eslint

is there a way to map the old global file location to the newly installed npm (using nvm)

Comment: fixed by adding prefix to .npmrc

prefix=C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: `nvm use node` instead of `nvm use 4`.

Comment: also useful to know
```export NODE_PATH=$(realpath $(dirname $(nvm which current))/../lib/node_modules)```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, there is no need to change the path to global modules folder over permissions,
as with active `nvm` node global modules are installed under specific version of node.

Try

```
$nvm install 16
...
$nvm version > .nvmrc

$ which npm
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npm
$ which node
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node
```

npm global install e.g. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
will install into
`/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules`

Remember to `nvm use`
to get back from `.nvmrc` to exact node version for which those global modules were installed.

`npm list -g --depth=0`
to list installed global modules